# JQUERY ajax вопрос насчет опций этого метода

Tags: jquery, ajax

в чем разница между вот такой записью

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax",
        type:"post",
        contentType:"application/text",
        data:city_number,
       success:
```

и вот такой записью

```
$.ajax({
            url:"ajax",
            type:"post",
             contentType:"text",
            data:city_number,
           success:
```

Т.Е. как понимать вот эту строку

```
contentType:"application/text",
```

И

```
contentType:"text",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вся суть в том, какую служебную информацию, с помощью заголовка **contentType:** вы сообщаете в запросе к серверу. Каждый сервер стремиться обрабатывать все возможные варианты, на основе документации.

1. [Properly Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)
2. [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

[image: JQUERY ajax вопрос насчет опций этого метода]